# Espresso test fails due to Android message `Viewing full screen, To exit, swipe down from the top`

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an espresso test which fails due to the Android pop up message which comes up `Viewing full screen. To exit, swipe down from the top`.

If I click `Got it` the test runs okay, but I have these tests running on build server where I cannot manually click it.

Emulator device I am running on - Nexus 7 API 23.

Is there a way I can disable this popup to come up or click it during the tests, but I am not sure though at what point this will popup.

Any ideas on how to handle this please.,

This is the popup Android throws which breaks the espresso test

[image]

I do get an error message due to this, which is as follows

Error on this line -

```
 onView(withId(R.id.prefuel_total))
                .perform(typeText(value), closeSoftKeyboard());

    androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click - At Coordinates: 1067, 321 and precision: 16, 16' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.
For more info check:

with id: com.ix.xx.staging:id/prefuel_total'.
at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:82)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:79)
at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:51)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:173)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:114)
at com.ix.xx.test.AbstractFuelOrderDataTests.enterPreFuelDataInDialog(AbstractFuelOrderDataTests.java:503)
at com.ix.xx.test.FuelOrderDataTests.testAcBatchOnlyProgress(FuelOrderDataTests.java:2782)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:61)
at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:527)
at org.mockito.internal.junit.VerificationCollectorImpl$1.evaluate(VerificationCollectorImpl.java:36)
at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:104)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:388)
at com.ix.xx.test.runner.UnlockDeviceAndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(UnlockDeviceAndroidJUnitRunner.java:42)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'Send down motion event' on view 'unknown'.
```

Thank you for ur help and suggestions
R

Comment: I'd first look at trying to figure out what is causing that dialog to appear. Is it happening randomly? Is your automation doing something specific?

Comment: Did you find the fix for this? The instrumentation test fails for me as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable these popups with the following command:

```
 adb shell settings put secure immersive_mode_confirmations confirmed
```

Comment: Hi can give me steps on where to run this command please

Comment: I would typically run this in a setup() method. It will have to be run after the emulator is launched. You'll likely want to look up the `executeShellCommand` command for syntax.

Comment: i tried running that in the setup command but it did not work.

Comment: was the emulator running at the time? did you receive any errors or is it simply not having the expected result?